Find a Lebesgue measurable set C
Suppose we are given Lebesgue measurable sets $A,B\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $A\subseteq B$ and $m^*(A)<m^*(B)$. Find a Lebesgue measurable set $C$ such that $A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ and $m^*(A)<m^*(C)<m^*(B)$.
To be honest, I don't even know how to start this one. It's obvious we need to find $D\subseteq B-A$ that $m^*(D)>0$ and $m^*(D)<m^*(B)-m^*(A)$, then $C=A\cup D$, but how to prove we can always find such a measurable set and it satisfies inequalities above?

Let $X=B-A$. Then $m^*(X)>0$, and your problem reduces to finding $D\subset X$ with $m^*(D)=\frac12 m^*(X)$.
So define a function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by
$$f(\xi)=m^*(X\cap[0,\xi])$$
$f(0)=0$, $f(1)=m^*(X)$, and $f$ is continuous. So there exists $\xi_0\in[0,1]$ such that $f(\xi_0)=\frac12 m^*(X)$. Now just set $D=X\cap[0,\xi_0]$.

should I prove $f$ is continuous? or is it obvious?

$f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)$ is the outer measure of a set contained in $[x,x+\epsilon]$ (or $[x+\epsilon,x]$ if $\epsilon<0$), so it must be $\le |\epsilon|$ in absolute value. Now just set $\delta=\epsilon$ in the definition of continuity.

Since $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable, so is $B-A$ (since the Lebesgue-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-Algebra). Because of $m^*(A) < m^*(B)$ we have $m^*(B-A) = m^*(B)-m^*(A) =\epsilon>0$ for some positive number $\epsilon$. Now to construct such a set $D$ as you mentioned we need to find a Lebesgue measurable subset $D$ of $B-A$ with $0 < m^*(D) < m^*(B-A)$ since then we can just take $C:= A \cup D$ and have
$$m^*(A) < m^*(A) + m^*(D) = m^*(A \cup D) = m^*(C) < m^*(C) + m^*(D\backslash (B-A) = m^*(B)$$
For that define $D_1:= [0,\frac 12] \cap (B-A)$ and $E_1:= (\frac 12, 1] \cap (B-A)$. Both sets are measurable because they are the intersection of two Lebesgue measurable sets. If $0<m^*(D_1) < m^*(B-A)$ or $0< m^*(E_1)< m^*(B-A)$ we are done and can take $D:= D_1$ or $D:= E_1$ respectively.
If this is not the case, there is one of the sets, say w.l.o.g. $D_1$ with $m^*(D_1) = m^*(B-A)$ (and the other set has measure zero) and we continue by halving $D_1$:
$$D_2:= [0, \frac 14] \cap D_1, \ E_2:= (\frac 14, \frac 12] \cap D_1.$$
From there we can iteratively continue. If $0<m^*(D_2) <m^*(B-A)$ take $D:= D_2$. Otherwise, one of the sets $D_2, E_2$ has measure $m^*(B-A)$ and we continue by halving this set. The process stops if one of the sets $D_k, E_k$thus constructed has a measure strictly between zero and $m^*(B-A)$.
Lastly, we argue why this process has to stop in finitely many steps: Let's assume that it doesn't stop. Then we will find, for every $n$, a set $D_n$ which is contained in an interval of length $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and has the measure $m^*(B-A) = \epsilon >0$. But for $n \to \infty$ this is a contradiction to the fact that $m^*(B-A)$ is positive. In other words, there is a step in our iterative construction in which the sets $D_k, E_k$ have gotten so small that they can't have the full measure of $m^*(B-A)$ anymore but need to have it split between $D_k$ and $E_k$. At this point we will have found our $D$.

Let $X=B\setminus A$, this is a measurable subset of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $p=m^*(X)\in(0,1)$. Your problem is to find a measurable set $Y\subseteq X$ such that $m^*(Y)\in(0,p)$. For any $t\in[0,1]$, define $X_t=X\cap [0,t]$. Call $f:t\mapsto m^*(X_t)$, then $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=p$. But $f(t)=\int_0^1\mathbf1_{X}(x)\mathrm d x$, thus $f$ is continuous and monotone increasing, thus you can find some $t$ such that $Y=X_t$ will solve your problem.

This is the same as my earlier answer.

Wow I'm from the phone I didn't see your answer while writing mine. It's really the same! Sorry

thanks! I have a question - what is b(x) in that integral?

By $\mathbf1_{X}$ I mean the indicator function defined as follows $$\mathbf1_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\textrm{if x\in X\0&\textrm{if }x\not\in X\end{cases}$$

As $A$ and $B$ are measurable, $m^*(A)=m(A)$ and $m^*(B)=m(B)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Notice that $B=B\backslash A\cup A$, and this union is disjoint. By additivity of measures this means that $m(B\backslash A)>0$. Set
$$\delta_1=\inf_a\{m([0,a]\cap B\backslash A)=0\},$$
and
$$\delta_2=\sup_a\{m([0,a]\cap B\backslash A)=m(B\backslash A)\}.$$
As $m(B\backslash A)>0$, $\delta_1<\delta_2$, and by definition $m([\delta_1,\delta_2]\cap B\backslash A)=m(B\backslash A)$. By definition of the supremum and infimum, for any $0<\varepsilon<\delta_2-\delta_1$,
$$0<m([\delta_1+\varepsilon,\delta_2]\cap B\backslash A)<m(B\backslash A)~,\text{and}~0<m([\delta_1,\delta_2-\varepsilon]\cap B\backslash A)<m(B\backslash A).$$
Thus just choose $C=[\delta_1+\varepsilon,\delta_2]\cap B\backslash A\cup A$ for your favourite choice of $\varepsilon$. As $C$ is again Lebesgue measurable (intervals are measurable)
$$m^*(C)=m(C)=m([\delta_1+\varepsilon,\delta_2]\cap B\backslash A)+m(A)<m(B\backslash A)+m(A)=m(B)=m^*(B),$$
and
$$m^*(C)=m(C)=m([\delta_1+\varepsilon,\delta_2]\cap B\backslash A)+m(A)>0+m(A)=m^*(A).$$
